# Link Image Thumbnail to the Same Image in a Slideshow in Different Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a masonry gallery, and currently, if you click on any of the thumbnails, it links to a slideshow in a different page, the the slideshow shows the first image no matter which thumbnail you click on. I'm wondering if there's a way to make it so the slideshow begins with the image that the thumbnail clicked on.

I tried this article, but doesn't seem to do it.

[Linking to specific headers on other pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440181/linking-to-specific-headers-on-other-pages?rq=1)

How I did is,

The thumbnail:

```
<a href="#the_slide">
            <div class="m_overlay"><div class="m_txt"><?php echo $image['title']; echo $image['caption'];?>"</div></div>
            <img src="<?php echo $image['url'];?>" title="<?php echo $image['title']; echo $image['caption'];?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>">
</a>
```

The image in the slideshow

```
       <?php
        global $post;
        $parent_id = $post->post_parent;
        $parentlink = get_permalink($parent_id);
        $images = get_field('gallery', $parent_id);
        ?>


        <ul class="slideshow">

        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
        <li>
            <h2 class="slideshow_title"><?php echo $image['title'];?></h2>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>


            <div class="slideshow_image"><a name="the_slide"></a><img src="<?php echo $image['url'];?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"></div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
```

I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: Did you create the slideshow? Or is it a plugin? If so, what plugin?

Comment: I'm using jQuery Cycle

Comment: Show us the code... `<a name="the_slide">` doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: jQuery Cycle doesn't natively support this. You could change the order you echo the images into the page with PHP using a $_GET variable.

Comment: @David: Could you elaborate it? I'm not familiar with PHP really.

Comment: So it looks like you are posting the gallery ID to your slideshow page, but on your link to this page ("/slideshow/.../index.php"), you could attach a $_GET variable of the thumbnail ID: "/slideshow/.../index.php?thumb=3". Then in your PHP, you could echo the image at that index using $_GET["thumb"] for the ID number, then go through your foreach, skipping the ID stored in $_GET["thumb"].

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of to do this, since it is not natively supported by your plugin, is to use $_GET variables to tell your page which image to echo first. It would look something like this:

On your gallery page, have the link to your slideshows contain a $_GET variable, called "thumb", that stores the ID number of the thumbnail you want to display first:

```
<a href="/slideshow/index.php?thumb=3"><img .../></a>
```

Where 3 represents the third thumbnail.

Then in your PHP file for the slideshow, you can change the echo order. Echo the image at the index of thumb (minus one for the zero index), followed by your for loop of the rest, skipping the image you already echoed (you can do this with `continue;`

```
<ul class="slideshow">

    <?php 
        $thumb = $_GET["thumb"];

        $firstImage = $images[$thumb-1];
        //echo first image here

        for($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++): 

        if($i == ($thumb-1)) continue;
        $image = $images[$i];
    ?>
    <li>
        <h2 class="slideshow_title"><?php echo $image['title'];?></h2>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>


        <div class="slideshow_image"><a name="the_slide"></a><img src="<?php echo $image['url'];?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"></div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </li>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where does the name "thumb" come from...? Do I need to add or define it somewhere?

Comment: I've tried it but it gives an internal server error when I click on a thumbnail.

Comment: Thumb is a variable that you are defining in the URL: `index.php?thumb=3` defines thumb as 3. Do you know what line the server error is coming from? Do you have access to the logs?

Comment: I did figure out to see the logs, but I'm ot sure what line the error is coming from. Do you think it has to do with that the site is built with Wordpress?

Comment: The fact that it was made with Wordpress shouldn't have an effect. A server error means that there's an error in the PHP code during `runtime`. So there are no syntax errors, but there's a problem with something running; I'm assuming it's the for loop.

Comment: the slideshow page says "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_INC, expecting ')'" in 'for($i = 0; $i < count($images); i++):'

Comment: Oh, I forgot the $ on the i++ in the for loop. Check the edit for the fix.

Comment: Just paste the log entry directly

Comment: Actually, I think I was looking at something else, and the hosting service support team says there is no error log generated yet.

Comment: It was a permission error, and so the hosting provider changed it to 755. Now it's showing this "Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header()"

Comment: Are you calling get_header somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it's a Wordpress template, so I need it.

Comment: Well make sure that it's defined before you call it