# can I link to a specific image among others that is on a different page?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a page of a carousel of images.  There is a link to a separate page of thumbnails for the carousel.  When in the page of thumbnails, I want to be able to click on any of them and be taken back to the carousel page to the associated image.  In the code below, clicking on the image "tree_2" takes me to the page of carousels with the first image in the carousel displayed.  How can I make the link back to the second image in the carousel ("tree_2")?

```html
<a href="gallery.html" <img src="_img/_img_new_build/tree_2.jpg" alt="tree"></a>
```

Comment: Untested: if the image in the carousel has an ID, try linking back to that: `href="gallery.html#tree_2"`. I don't know if that will work. Maybe, but probably only if the image happens to be showing at the time.

Comment: Thanks.  I did try that, and it just takes me back to the first image in the carousel.  I found this post that addresses the problem, but the solution given was not marked as an answer and was fairly complicated, and involved javascript.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444395/link-image-thumbnail-to-the-same-image-in-a-slideshow-in-different-page  I'm guessing this is a somewhat complicated problem and may be above my paygrade.